# messaging/unknown.. The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error -34018.)]

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing push notifications on iPhone designed for mac from Xcode, I tried to run the app on the iPhone simulator and I can get the Token successfully. and on android, it worked perfectly too. But when I run on ( iPhone designed for mac ) I get this error

[messaging/unknown] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error -34018.)]

I am using `'@react-native-firebase/messaging'`

I searched and it seems the problem is related to keychain access, here is an old answer I found on the GitHub issue

```
You need to clean your keychain cache since you made some critical changes on certificates.
Go to Keychain Access -> login -> Passwords
and make sure you removed all below items.

[your firebase project number.*]
[your app bundle ID]
com.google.iid.checkin
```

I tried this, but the problem still exists.

Here is my code to get the token.

```
  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await messaging().getToken();

      console.log('============= messaging token =============');
      console.log({token});

      await saveItem(AsyncKeys.DEVICE_TOKEN, {device_token: token});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('======== error post token ==========');
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: need to pod install for ios

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean your keychain cache since you made some critical changes on certificates.

Go to **Keychain Access -> login -> Passwords**

and make sure you removed all below items.

- [your firebase project number.*]
- [your app bundle ID]
- com.google.iid.checkin